# Entry#user_ids を更新する view の書き方を教えて下さい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

entry has_many users な関係で、以下のような params を構築するには view をどのように書いたらいいでしょうか?

`{entry: { user_ids: [1, 2] }}`

尚、以下の記述だと `{ user_ids: [1, 2] }` となってしまいます。まぁ、これでもいいのですが、、、、

```rb
<%= form_for @entry, url: update_users_entry_path do |f| %>
  <% @entry.users.each do |user| %>
    <%= number_field_tag "user_ids[]", user.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

要は以下の html が作りたいのです。

```
<input id="entry_user_ids_1" type="text" name="entry[user_ids][]" value="1">
<input id="entry_user_ids_2" type="text" name="entry[user_ids][]" value="2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようにすれば、`{"entry" => {"user_ids" => [...]}}` の形式で渡されます。

```
<% f.object.users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <%= number_field_tag "entry[user_ids][]", user.id, :id => "entry_user_ids_#{index}" %>
<% end %>
```

レールに乗るのであれば、`fields_for` を利用する方法もあります。この場合、`{"entry" => {"entry_user_mappings_attributes" => {"0" => {"id" => ..., "user_id" => ...}, "1" => {"id" => ..., "user_id" => ...}}}}` の形で渡されますが、そのまま update にパラメータとして与えることで更新できます。(`entry_user_mappings` は中間テーブル名です。適宜置き換えてください。)

```
<%= f.fields_for :entry_user_mappings do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.number_field :user_id %>
<% end %>
```

※strong parameters の対応 (`entry_params` を変更) を忘れずに。(後者は`accepts_nested_attributes_for` の設定も)